# Is it fair to withhold test and assignment memorandums at tertiary educational institutes?

Tags: teaching, computer-science

I have a module at university that broadly covers data structures and algorithms. The subject coordinator of said module simply refuses to supply any feedback or opportunities to students that want to learn from their mistakes.

He states that doing so does not promote students to think for themselves, or simply that no such documents (i.e. memorandums) exists (which I know to be false).

Is this rationale generally accepted amongst lecturers?
Is it fair to deprive students the opportunity to learn from their mistakes?

Comment: _no such documents (i.e. memorandums) exists (which I know to be false)_ Did you actually see the  memorandum?

Comment: @scaaahu Assignments are marked by an automated system, that compiles uploaded files and then evaluate the output of these files. The output of a student’s files is compared to the output produced by the system.  For the system to produce the correct output, there must exist files that contain the content that define the outcomes of the assignment.

Comment: This seems to be partly a matter of opinion.  I daresay your lecturer would disagree that this "deprives students of the opportunity to learn from their mistakes", and might say that students are perfectly capable of learning from their mistakes by studying what they did, comparing with books and outside resources, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be many reasons why no feedback is given; complexity of the undertaking, legal issues, organisation etc. However, not promoting students thinking for themselves, as reason, simply does not make sense. Of course, students need feedback. Assuming, however, you got feedback during the course, the feedback from the assessment is not really central anymore.

Comment: I think that `Assuming, however, you got feedback during the course` is a pretty big assumption in general. In some cultures, there are no feedback opportunities before the exam.

Comment: _Of course, students need feedback_
This is the point that I want to make, students’ should be granted the opportunity to detect their error, so that they can improve at that specific error, and avoid it in the future.

Comment: _Assuming, however, you got feedback during the course, the feedback from the assessment is not really central anymore._
@CaptainEmacs
I agree, but in my case, tutor may be contacted with a specific problem, in the hope that the tutor will be able to clarify said problem. This is regarded as feedback from their side, but this method provides no means to detect what a student struggled with in the assignment. It also creates an unnecessary dependency with the tutor, as the detection could easily have been resolved by the student himself, if appropriate documents were provided.

Comment: @AndrejaKo Is it then **common** for said cultures to get no feedback from their educators? How it that called education, or am I misunderstanding how education is defined?

Comment: @AndrejaKo Well, that's bad. Few people can learn without feedback. To MSR: well, in principle, I agree, but feedback is needed in the run-up to the assessment. If the assess is the core point of failure when everything else  went well, then we are facing another problem. Yes, in an ideal world, the exam would be inspectable. But at this stage, such exams are only about assessment, not feedback anymore, which should have been given earlier.

Comment: @MSR It is usually common to get feedback after the exam, so that later on, in professional life, the mistakes can be corrected. Of course, there are some examiners that do not want to give any feedback. Usually, they are the exception, but they still exist. Unfortunately, the most the students do about the issue is to call them bad names behind their backs. At my current university, we've had a case that was so bad, that in the end, the entire module was removed from the curriculum.